# AngularJS Ngblur get incomplete input value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just wondering why the ngblur directive did not get the complete value of a text input. I am using easyautocomplete plugin to do search through a JSON file.

When it found it will list out several suggestions that could be match to the input. The problem is when we do not type the full text and choose to select from the provided list, ngblur will only capture what we have typed to the input box instead of what we choose from the list.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zvezrg6j/

json country is `Indonesia` or `Singapore` or `Thailand`

**UPDATE**

What i wanted to do is when i choose from the list or when i leave the text input with full text, the app will look up for some details, eg. after typing the country the app will look for its capital.

Comment: You have to define `data`: `$scope.data = {};`

Comment: does not solve the problem ,still the same. updated fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/zvezrg6j/2/

Comment: it will only display the input value typed because when you choose the option from the list the input field loses its focus with the last typed value. The ngblur event will not be triggered after this action.

Comment: any workaround for this?

Comment: I have provided a solution in the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution you are looking for.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvezrg6j/6/)

Instead of calling `FindMaterialDetail` method on `blur`, call it `onHideListEvent` of auto-complete options.

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $scope.FindMaterialDetail = function(country) {
                   var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
                   scope.$apply(function(){
                   scope.data.result = country;
          })

        }

        var options = {
                      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rjn5",
                      getValue: "country",
                      listLocation: "data",
                      list: {
                        match: {
                          enabled: true
                        },
                        onHideListEvent: function() {    
                              $scope.FindMaterialDetail($("#Autocomplete").val());
                          }
                      }
            };
            $("#Autocomplete").easyAutocomplete(options);
    });
```

Comment: is there a way that can split the autcomplete and directly injected to the body of the document instead of write in the angular module, i am trying to have a clean angular module which only consist of any related to angular only,

Comment: Updated my fiddle, please have a look at the latest fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The option you can try is using $scope.$watch for the model. Instead of calling the function in ngblur try adding the following snippet in your script.

```
 $scope.$watch("data.country", function(event) {
      $scope.data.result = $scope.data.country;
    });
```

Please find the modified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5cmL7un/).

Comment: yours code is great, however i need to lookup for some details for any chosen country, if i am not mistaken using $watch will keep every changes and do queries to the api which i dont want to, i just want to perform the queries when the function called. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Your understanding is correct. $watch will be triggered when there is a change in the model. Please update your question with details of what you are trying to achieve and how you want the solution to be.

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot think of a way to find out if the user has typed in or chosen the full text. The solutions that I can think of are calling the function using $watch or ng-change and return the details as soon as it finds one (or) use a button where the click event calls the function to retrieve the details. If you find any alternative please post it here so that even I can know about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because blur event is firing before value update in 'data.country', You can resolve this issue by using below code. Create A directive like below-

```
 angular.module('app', []).directive('easyAutoComplete', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 1, // needed for angular 1.2.x
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
          var options = {
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rjn5",
  getValue: "country",
  listLocation: "data",
  list: {
    match: {
      enabled: true
    },
     onChooseEvent: function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {
                             ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($(elm).getSelectedItemData().country);
                });    

     }
  },

};
      $(elm).easyAutocomplete(options);
        }
    };
});
```

then use it like as -

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="data.country" easy-auto-complete ng-change="FindMaterialDetail(data.country)" id="Autocomplete">
```

Comment: added your code the the fiddle, but it does not solve the problem. please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/zvezrg6j/3/

Comment: Thank you for the code, learn something new here, but i have a question, what if i have another JSON file, lets say i have a list of city JSON file, is it mean i have to create another directive again? could be the code reuseable?

Comment: No, You need to make it reusable by creating isolated scope of the directive and passing changeable fields/values

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on loading jquery autocomplete Plugin in your angular code , as the angular code got initialized first followed by the autocomplete .
So i've converted the  above code to Angular Bootstrap Typehead which is exactly does  the autocomplete written in angular way .It's also recommended to use angular directives rather than jquery plugins for building angular applications

Check for Custom templates for results on this link.

[Angular Autocomplete TypeAhead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshwar33/Lu7ryeLc/2/)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.country" placeholder="Custom template"  uib-typeahead="country as country  for country in Countries"  typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0" ng-blur="FindMaterialDetail(data.country)"   class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, as for the bootstrap for angular, there is a problem because i am using semantic-ui as the frontend platform which will be conflicted to each other.